# how to enable AllowEncodedSlashes in ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu

as the title say i have difficulties to enable AllowEncodedSlashes in Ubuntu

i put

> AllowEncodedSlashes On

inside /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and inside /etc/apache2/sites-available/default but still got 404 page after access url with encoded slashes
[image: error 404 not found]

Comment: title should be how to enable AllowEncodedSlashes with apache :)

Answer (score 0):

I was searching a lot for this. But can't find a clear answer for Ubuntu 14.4 and Apache 2.4.7 . I figured it out. Here's what I did:

Go to `/etc/apache2/sites-available`

Open the 000-default.conf file.

add `AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode`inside the `<VirtualHost>` tag

Save and restart Apache.

** `apache2.conf` modification is not needed. Modify only `000-default.conf` file and not `default-ssl.conf`

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
AllowEncodedSlashes On
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests Off
ServerName www.domain.com
ServerAlias domain.com
Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

If your domain is secure with ssl certificate then you shuold also use with 443 port

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ProxyPreserveHost On
AllowEncodedSlashes On
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCertificateFile /home/ubuntu/domain.com/example.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/ubuntu/domain.com/example.com.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /home/ubuntu/domain.com/intermediate.crt
SSLCACertificateFile /home/ubuntu/domain.com/intermediate.crt
<FilesMatch “\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$”>
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>
BrowserMatch “MSIE [2–6]” \
nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch “MSIE [17–9]” ssl-unclean-shutdown
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```